# mysql incremental replication from remote DB

Tags: php, mysql

We are developing a web application using mysql and php. 
In our application, we are expected to sync our local mysql database with a remote mysql database ( running on a different host) based on a trigger from the user interface.

User trigger is in the form of a webpage and when the user clicks on a button, the php server script is fired which should perform this synchronization in the background.

We planned to do it in a simple way by opening db connection with the remote and local db and inserting the rows, one row at a time. But the size of the remote DB table can be very high ( as big as a few million entries) and hence we need a more efficient solution.

Can someone help us with the sql query / php code which can do this db sync in an efficient manner without burdening the remote DB too much.

Thanks in advance

Shyam

**UPDATE**
The remote DB is not in my control so I cannot configure it as master or do any other settings on it. So that is one major limitation I have.  That is why I want to do it programatically using php. Another option I have is to read blocks of 1000 rows from remote DB and insert into the local DB. But I wanted to know if there is a better way ?

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel if MySQL already has replication capabilities?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't concern yourself with MySQL replication from an application layer when the data layer has this functionality built-in. Please read up on "Master/Slave replication with MySQL". https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql is a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The cost of replication is minimal as far as the Master is concerned. It basically works like this:

1. The Master logs all (relevant) activity into a flat log file
2. The Slave downloads this log every now and then and replays the binary log locally

Therefore, the impact on the Master is only writing linear data to a log file, plus a little bit of bandwidth. If you still worry about the impact on the Master, you could throttle the link between Master and Slave (at the system level), or just open the link during low activity times (by issuing [`STOP/START SLAVE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stop-slave.html) commands at appropriate times).

I should also mention that built-in replication takes place at a low level inside the MySQL engine. I do not think you can achieve better performance with an external process. If you want to fully sinchronise your local dtabase when you hit this "Synchronise" button, then look no further.

If you can live with partial synchronisation, then you could have this button resume replication for a short timeframe (eg. `START SLAVE` for 10 secondes and `STOP SLAVE` again automatically; the user needs to click again to get more data) synchronised.